# What does symbol # means in #define S(x) (cout<<#x<<endl)

Tags: c++, c, syntax, c-preprocessor

```
#define S(x) (cout<<#x<<endl)
```

Using # will print whatever string, int, float I place in S(x).
**For example:**

```
S(Door Class Default Constructor);
```

**will print**

> Door Class Default Constructor

I Wasn't able to find any documentation regarding it.
Explain how is it able to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It causes the expanded `x` to be wrapped in double quoates, `"`

It's often called the stringize operator and you can find more information [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).